# Loop through a directory in Talend

Tags: loops, directory, talend

I have a Directory with many sub-directories in it including one named as OLD. This OLD folder could also be inside any of the sub directories and contains archived files.

- Root Directory A

  - SUB-DIRECTORY A

    - file1.txt
    - file2.txt
  - SUB-DIRECTORY B

    - file1.txt
    - file2.txt
    - OLD
  - SUB-DIRECTORY C

    - file1.txt
    - file2.txt
  - SUB-DIRECTORY D

    - file1.txt
    - OLD
    - SUB-SUB-DIRECTORY E

      - file7.txt
      - OLD

I need to create a job in Talend which shall look for all OLD folders (in main and in sub directory both) and delete the files from that folder. I can use tFilelist to and mask the files to be deleted. But unable to figure out how to configure the job to look for OLD folder in all sub directories and delete those files also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is in the tFileList put your main folder choose check box include sub directories and in the FileList type drop down list choose Directories. Your file mask should be "OLD" or if it is anything more "*OLD*".
Iterate and use the parameter ((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH"))
to capture your sub directories. Now you can use this folder path in a tFileDelete Which can also delete folders

Comment: Thanks...for the suggestion...i tried this but this will delete the folder OLD...bit I need to delete the files inside OLD and not the folder OLD..... :(

Comment: this is not a problem, so instead of directly putting a tFileDelete use another tFileList to iterate on each OLD folder you found: ((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH"))  this time you look for files only with mask *. Iterate on the results FULL FILE PATH with the tFileDelete.

Comment: Hey...that worked for me....Thanks a lot !!!! I was able to achieve what was required....Thanks for ur help!!!! Much appreciated...  :)

Answer (score 0):

follow below approach..

1. Add tFileList and configure to Travers over all the directories.
2. now use if conndition connection from tFileList
3. Add tJava and connect with iterator connection
4. Add tFileDelete after tJava and connect with IF condition.
5. Add below condition inside if condition.

   `((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_2_CURRENT_FILEPATH")).contains("OLD")`
6. Now you will get the all files from all the directories above code will give pass to the files which has the "OLD" in there file path.

I have not tested but you can try it.